# How do I add a password to an already created localuser using -AsSecureString parameter in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, passwords, addition

I'm somewhat new to powershell and I'm taking a class that asked me to create a localuser then after the localuser is created to add a password using -assecurestring parameter. I had no issue creating the localuser while adding a password from the documentation looks straightforward although I keep getting errors. All my google searches have sent me on endless loops with the same information that's not working. Please Help

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @Dcommand Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64923201/edit) and add the commands + error (code doesn't format well in comments as you can see)

Comment: I'm using set-localuser - name "User02" -password

Comment: @Dcommand The error message starts with "Get-Process : " - where does that come from?

Comment: It comes right from the documentation page of powershell. This seems like it should be a very straightforward process. For some reason it not. What is the command that you would use? Thanks for the help . I've also used every combination of set-localuser but to no avail.

Comment: I'm saying there's a discrepancy between what you claim to be running and the error message you posted in the previous comment - if the error message starts with "Get-Process : " then that's because the command throwing the error is `Get-Process`. So either _don't call `Get-Process`_, or tell us _exactly which commands you are running_ if you want help figuring out what's wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in the PowerShell help files and examples.

```
Find-Module -Name '*localuser*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

Version Name                Repository Description                                                   
------- ----                ---------- -----------                                                   
3.0     LocalUserManagement PSGallery  a module that performs various local user management functions

# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Set-LocalUser).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Set-LocalUser).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Set-LocalUser -Examples
# Results
<#
Set-LocalUser -Name "Admin07" -Description "Description of this account."
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$UserAccount = Get-LocalUser -Name "User02"
$UserAccount | Set-LocalUser -Password $Password
#>
Get-help -Name Set-LocalUser -Full
Get-help -Name Set-LocalUser -Online
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I was missing the first line set-localuser - name "User02"... everything else was exactly what I used from the documentation page.